# SocketTimeoutException - "timeout" "read timed out"

Tags: exception, timeout, retrofit, okhttp

I am writing tests which run OkHttp/Retrofit requests against a MockWebServer. Among other things I'm **testing timeouts**. Here I noticed, that some of my timeout tests *do not produce the same kind of exception all the time*:

While the exception thrown is always a `SocketTimeoutException`, the **exception message differs** between two possibilities. Sometimes I get

- `"timeout"`, sometimes
- `"Read timed out"`.

There seems to be no clear pattern (it's the very same test which sometimes produces one or the other of these exception messages).

I assume that different constellations/causes lead to the differing messages... Can somebody explain to me the difference between these two cases?

---

Here are the corresponding stack traces:

**"Read timed out"**

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:238)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:381)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:45)
    at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingRequestBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:279)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:386)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1287)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1016)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:787)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:739)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:714)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$35$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:910)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:117)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:106)
```

**"timeout"**

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:212)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:288)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:242)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:381)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:45)
    at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingRequestBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:279)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:386)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1287)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1016)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:787)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:739)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:714)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$35$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:910)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:117)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:106)
```

Comment: Can you include the actual Exception stacktraces?

Comment: @YuriSchimke: stack traces added

Comment: Non authoritative answer: I suspect it differs based on whether it has read anything from the stream or not. But it seems like something not worth worrying too much about, just check the exception type.