# SocketTimeoutException for all kind of timeouts in OkHttp

Tags: android, timeout, retrofit, okhttp, socket-timeout-exception

When communicating with a server from an Android device, timeouts happen and I'd like to make a difference between read timeouts and other timeouts. In other words, I'd like to know if there is a chance that the request has reached the server and that the timeout happened because the response has been too slow to get back.

So far, I found out in Android app logs that no matter the timeout, the same [`SocketTimeoutException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketTimeoutException) happens. Only the exception message changes. Sometimes it's clear it's a connection error `"failed to connect to ... from ... after 10000ms: isConnected failed"` (even though I just discovered there is also a [ConnectTimeoutException](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ConnectTimeoutException)) and other times it's just `"timeout"`. It seems it could well be the read timeout.

So far though, I haven't found any resource confirming this in OkHttp documentation or on Stackoverflow. Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640281/sockettimeoutexception-timeout-read-timed-out) suggests there are actually multiple different messages for a read timeout.

In the end, how can I figure if the timeout happened before the connection with the server was established, when sending the request content to the server or when waiting for a response from the server?

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47504500/8357735

Comment: @farid thank you for your help, I'm not really trying to find the right timeout value, I just want to know whether the request timed out when sending the request or receiving the response. In some cases, you want things to fail fast and you want to know it failed.

Comment: its your decision dude and depends on the average response time on your server!